# Elements shifting when screen is resized

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-position

I'm currently having some problems with the positioning of the elements on my page. When full screen the elements are centred and don't overlap.

[image]

However, when the screen is resized the elements shift to the left and start overlapping

[image]

I was wondering how to go about fixing this?

Heres my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8711e0b6fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="content-wrapper">  
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">[My Coily Story]</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Scenes/index.html">Scenes</a></li>
            <li><a href="./About/index.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="./Contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>

<div class="collage"></div>

<audio id="player" src="1.mp3"></audio>
<div class="player" >
    <div class="control">
        <i class="fas fa-play" id="playbtn"></i>
</div>
<div class="info">
    Kathleen Cleaver - Natural Hair
<div class="bar">
    <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
</div>
    <div id="current">0:00</div>
</div>

<div class="start">
<a href="./Page/index.html">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>   
    Start
</a>
</div>
    
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arcade';
    src: url(fonts/ARCADECLASSIC.TTF);
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: Regular;
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    transition: all 0.35s linear;
}

body {
   background-color: black;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   scroll-behavior: none;
}
header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.875rem 6.25rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    z-index: 10000;
}

header .logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.313rem;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;

}

.logo:hover{
   pointer-events: none;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   background: transparent;
}

header ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: none;

}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 1.25rem;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: none;

}

header ul li a {
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 0.375rem 0.938rem;
     color: #fff;
     border-radius: 1.25rem;
     font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.1rem;
     text-transform: none;
     position: sticky;


}

header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
    background: #fff;
    color: #2b1055;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: none;
    position: sticky;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.collage {
    background: url(./Images/1.gif);
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 61%;
    width: 55%;
    border: solid 8px;
    border-color: white;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 55%;
    max-width: 55%;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 20%;
    left: 27%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;

}

.player {
    width: 55%;
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 48px 1fr 48px;
    color: white;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 33%;
    left: 65%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
}    

.control, #current {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-block: 16px;
}

#playbtn {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#playbtn:hover {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}

.info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 21px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    

    

}

#current {
    text-align: right;
}

.bar {
    --space:  -4px;
    background-color: #24242424;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: var(--space);
    right: var(--space);
    top: var(--space);
    bottom: var(--space);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 64px;
    z-index: -2;
}

#progress {
    display: block;
    width: var(--progress, 0%);
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    z-index: 10000;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    color: #d4337e;
    font-family: arcade;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.2s;
    position: relative;

}

.start {
    position: relative;
    top: 42%;
    left: 31%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 55%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
  

}
a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #d4337e;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #d4337e, 0 0 40px #d4337e, 0 0 80px #d4337e;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}

a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,#d4337e);
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1) {
    left: 100%;
    transition: 1s;
}

a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg,transparent,#d4337e);
}

a:hover span:nth-child(3) {
    right: 100%;
    transition: 1s; 
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
} 

a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg,transparent,#d4337e);
}

a:hover span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 100%;
    transition: 1s; 
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}   

a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg,transparent,#d4337e);
}

a:hover span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: 100%;
    transition: 1s; 
    transition-delay: 0.75s;
}
```

JS

```
var player = document.getElementById("player");
let progress = document.getElementById("progress");
let playbtn = document.getElementById("playbtn");

var playpause = function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
    } else {
        player.pause();
    }
}

playbtn.addEventListener("click", playpause);

player.onplay = function () {
    playbtn.classList.remove("fa-play");
    playbtn.classList.add("fa-pause");
}

player.onpause = function () {
    playbtn.classList.add("fa-play");
    playbtn.classList.remove("fa-pause");
}   

player.ontimeupdate = function () {
    let ct = player.currentTime;
    current.innerHTML = timeFormat(ct);
    ///progress
    let duration = player.duration;
    prog = Math.floor((ct * 100) / duration);
    progress.style.setProperty("--progress",prog + "%");
}

function timeFormat(ct) {
    minutes = Math.floor(ct / 60);
    seconds = Math.floor(ct % 60);

    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0"+seconds;
    }

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you plan your element positioning on display relative or absolute.
on the other hand you should build your layout with flexbox